# Rails 4 Create Unique Identifier For Pair of Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use a unique identifier for a pair of users to create rooms identifiers for a messaging model: simply concatenating ids won't work, the following is not unique

```
#{user1_id+user2_id}
```

I was thinking about creating small unique tokens for each user when they re created with

```
rand(36**8).to_s(36)
```

And then concatenate the tokens, in that case that would be unique.

Is there the need to create such tokens, or anyone has experience with creating unique identifiers for a pair of users?

Comment: Is room an ActiveRecord model?

Comment: No, I could have made it a join table, but using ids like so also allows to add more users to the "room" without adding columns each time

Comment: I know you said it didn't work anyway, but FYI when you do this `#{user1_id+user2_id}` it will only concatenate them if they are strings.  If they are numbers (which an id would normally be) then they will be added mathematically.

Comment: you re right, wrote it quickly just to show the idea

Comment: You could create a room model and a join table between rooms and users, getting HABTM (with potential possibility to add as many users to any room as you want). Still, I can see cases when it's not desirable, so it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept a string value for your composite id can you just join the user ids together with a separator:

```
"#{user1_id}:#{user2_id}"
```

I've used a colon but you could use anything that you know won't appear in the user ids themselves.

One thing to watch out for is whether the order of the ids is important in your composite (i.e. is there a first user and a second user - or is the composite for two users the same regardless of who is first or second).

You may want to do `[user1_id, user2_id].sort.join(":")` to generate the composite as that will always return the ids in the same order.